# How to display invoice in vs2012 vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, crystal-reports, rdlc

I am working on Visual Studio 2012 with VB.net. I have sales pages from where the customer details go to a `sale` table and product details goes to `saleprod` table from a `GridView`. I want to generate an invoice based on the invoice number (inv is my primary key used in sale table and foreign key in saleprod table).

How can I generate the data from two tables in one Crystal Report or RDLC report? I can fetch one product details from `saleprod` table easily, but if one invoice has many products then it's not coming up. As an example, invoice number 1 has 5 products then I want to display all 5 products in the invoice, but that's not happening. I have tried subreport also but it's showing all the invoices like 1, 2, 3 etc.. I only want for particular one invoice.

[table_details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8pQI.png)

Report and sub report code.

```
Private Sub invoice_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'billdata.saleprod' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.saleprodTableAdapter.Fill(Me.billdata.saleprod)
    'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'billdata.sale' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
    Me.saleTableAdapter.Fill(Me.billdata.sale)

    AddHandler Me.ReportViewer1.LocalReport.SubreportProcessing, AddressOf subEventHandler

    Me.ReportViewer1.RefreshReport()
End Sub

Public Sub subEventHandler(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SubreportProcessingEventArgs)
    Dim subrepo As DataTable
    subrepo = Me.billdata.Tables("saleprod")
    Dim strfilter As String
    strfilter = e.Parameters("invp").Values.First()
    Me.saleprodTableAdapter.Fillsaleprod(Me.billdata.saleprod, strfilter)
    e.DataSources.Add(New ReportDataSource("subprod", subrepo))
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow. Take your time to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: You need to show us a lot more, pushpesh. Can you add the design of your tables and the SQL that you used to pull the information, please? It does look like you're going to need two SQL queries, however, one to pull the invoices in the main report, and one to pull the products in your sub report.  They should be linked on the invoice number.  Is this a college project?

Comment: hi, i have edited post and showed you table pic, and code for  report and subreport